# HTML Grid checkbox C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, grid

I need to create a checkbox on the Html.Grid to toggle a value if its checked. I've tried it in two ways but it doesn't seem to work. The checkboxes appear fine but the they don't change the values.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Items).Columns(columns =>
{

    //columns.Add(m => m.PacketPrinting).Titled(_("Print")).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).SetWidth(10).RenderValueAs(m => Html.CheckBox("PacketPrinting", false));
    //columns.Add(m => m.PacketPrinting).Titled(_("Print")).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Format("<input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"m.PacketPrinting\"></input>");
    columns.Add(m => m.Id).Titled(_("ID num.")).Sanitized(false).Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(m => Html.ActionLink(m.Id.ToString(), MVC.Customs.ECSPrispetje.Details((m.Id))));
    columns.Add(m => m.IdRef).Titled(_("Ref. num."));
}).Selectable(false).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true).OrderByDescending(x => x.DatumPriprave)
```

In the `Model.Items` I have a value `PacketPrinting` and I'd like to set it to true when the checkbox is checked so I can than check which check boxes where checked and print all of them from my Controller.

Thanks.

Edit:

Maybe anyone knows if its possible to make a List of checked files in the cshtml and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: And what does "it doesn't seem to work" mean? Checkbox is not displayed, value is not posted to controller, etc? Please be specific

Comment: The checboxes are displayed fine and i can toggle them and everything but when I press print all the Items still have the PacketPrinting set to false.